# Pass TextView to an Intent in Android

Tags: android, exception, textview

In new project in Android I have a layout with a TextView and a TabWidget in the main.xml file.

My tab menu launches different activities using Intents, in these activities I need to do:

```
TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.titolo);
        title.setText("Home");
```

but I can do this only in the main activity while if I try to do this in other activities I get a nullpointer exception.. What is the problem?

In the manifest I inserted other activities like this, is this the problem?

```
<activity android:name="List1"></activity>
```

I tryed using

```
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View row = li.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
TextView title = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.titolo);
```

I get no errors but the title didn't change

Comment: So how you set value for textview? can you put that code (of getview method).

Answer (score 1):

A TextView with that ID needs to be present in all your activity layouts. You are getting a NullPointerException as Android can not find the view. Also make sure you are setting the layout in onCreate properly using **setContentView**.

Comment: I can't add setContentView(R.layout.main);, I reopen the layout in the tab and I get error, other activity doesn't use a layout.. What I have to do?

Comment: All activities need to have a layout if you are using findViewById. Sorry, I did not get what you meant by reopening the layout in the tab. In my answer, I am referring to the layout files in /res/layout.

Comment: if I call setContentView(R.layout.main) in the activity contained in the tab, In the tab is displayed all the layout including the tab layout so the layout tab opens "recursively"

Comment: You need to set a different layout for your other activities.

Answer (score 1):

The `TextView` with this id (titolo) must be a child of the layout of the `Activity` where you use this code.

```
TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.titolo);
if(title != null)
    title.setText("Home");
else
    Log.e(TAG, "title TextView not found in current layout);
```

If you'r trying to implement a Actionbar of some sort, try creating a "actionbar.xml" (containing the `TextView` with the id "titolo") for example and include it in all your layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Your manifest should be as

```
<activity android:name=".List1"></activity>
```

In `List1` activity

```
setContentView(set_layout_which_contains_titolo) and then use 

TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.titolo);
        title.setText("Home");
```

But if your work may be done as to send string (which contains value of text view) to calling activity.
It will work.